# Error when creating a ListView in React Native

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I am trying to create a simple `ListView` in React Native.

My code works correctly when using the Chrome debugger, but not when it is disconnected.

Here is what I think is the problem area:

```
getInitialState() { 
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    return {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]), 
    };
},
```

And here is the error in XCode:

> 2016-04-10 09:31:20.013 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] One
>   of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype
>   chain. This is an edge case that we do not support. This error is a
>   performance optimization and not spec compliant. 2016-04-10
>   09:31:20.015 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Failed to
>   print error: ', 'One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key
>   on the prototype chain. This is an edge case that we do not support.
>   This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.'
>   2016-04-10 09:31:20.016 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript]
>   undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new
>   _reactNative.ListView.DataSource') 2016-04-10 09:31:20.016 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Failed to print error: ',
>   'One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype
>   chain. This is an edge case that we do not support. This error is a
>   performance optimization and not spec compliant.'

Note that when I remove the `ListView` code above, the app works correctly.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Version 0.22.2. I fixed the problem by moving back to `React.createClass` from `extends Component`. Unfortunately I can't give reproduction steps.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this problem besides changing from extends Component, as mentioned by sdgfsdh.